# Append array with variable

Tags: php, arrays

So what I am doing is creating a function that will pass in what array to append to another array. Here is what I am "trying" to do:

```
Global $shirts;
Global $prices;

$shirts = array(
        'Option1' => array(),
        'Option2' => array(),
    );

$prices = array(
        'product1' => array(
                        'bronze' => 1, 
                        'silver' => 2, 
                        'gold' => 3,
                       ),
        'product2' => array(
                        'bronze' => 4, 
                        'silver' => 5, 
                        'gold' => 6,
                       ),  
    );


function shirts($shirts_model) {

        global $shirts;
        global $prices;

        foreach ($shirts => $shirt) {

            $result = array_merge($shirt, $prices[$shirt_model]);

        }
         print_r($result);  

    }

shirts('product2');
```

so now the `$shirts` array would now look like:

```
$shirts = array(
            'Option1' => array(
                            'bronze' => 4, 
                            'silver' => 5, 
                            'gold' => 6,
                           ),
            'Option2' => array(
                            'bronze' => 4, 
                            'silver' => 5, 
                            'gold' => 6,
                           ),
        );
```

with the "product2" array. Basically now I could call the `shirts();` function and pass in any option to append that options array to the shirts array. But this approach is not working? I am getting a white screen and I dont think this is working.

Hope that made sense.

Comment: And your exact question is what?

Comment: Y echo $shirts??? Why not print_r($result); ??

Comment: Do u want to return merged array in result?

Comment: Sorry, changed the question. But yes I want to just make sure that the shirts array is now listing with the whatever option array I choose added.

Comment: can you explain your expected results

Comment: If u r not getting anything in print_r($result);   than on error_reporting()

Comment: Don't know but error should be this foreach ($shirts => $shirt) {

Comment: This should be $shirts as $shirt

Comment: @Gavriel I expect to $shirts array that has a blank array within it to now contain the select option array from the prices.

Comment: What's w/ all the `Global` / `global` declarations.  Is that normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments now I am convert it into answer.

First of all you need to fix your `foreach()` function as:

```
foreach($array as $value)
```

**Modified code:**

```
function shirts($shirts_model) 
{ 
    global $shirts, $prices; 

    foreach ($shirts as $key => $shirt) 
    { 
        $result[$key] = $prices[$shirts_model];
    } 
    return $result;
}
```

**Now calling it:**

```
$record = shirts('product2');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($record);
```

**Error Reporting:**

Add `error_reporting` **ON** in your code this will help you to find out the issue.

```
error_reporting();
```

Comment: Hmmmm this makes sense but returns nothing. I am not getting the white screen of death, just nothing.

Comment: @packy don't know but use global not Global

Comment: Thanks. Still not printing anything but I will poke around with it

Comment: @packy r u using my code???? I have updated it.. Was using shirt_model this should be shirts_model

Comment: @packy ahan glad to know your problem is solve don't forgot to appreciate. Happy coding

Comment: 2 problems: 1. you just copied my answer :( 2. you have an error because you forgot to declare $result

Comment: @gavriel I made it same mistake just. But debug it to. And for error yes u can declare array in default but I think here it will not hurt yes agreed good practice to declare it in default.

Answer (score 1):

```
function shirts($shirt_model) {
    global $shirts;
    global $prices;

    // create an empty array for the results
    $results = array();

    // loop so that you have both the key, value, and we'll only use the key
    foreach ($shirts as $option => $shirt) {
        // just add the prices to the results
        $results[$option] = $prices[$shirt_model]);
    }
    return $results;  
}
```

Comment: My friend u have an small issue this is shirts_model not shirt_model

Comment: Glad to know my friend u earn my vote I suggest also add some story of foreach()